# How does type conversion affect the memory accessed by the program and its variables?

Tags: c++, memory-management

If I have the following code:

```
int variable = 65;
double variable2 = 54.34;
double sum = (double)variable + variable2;
```

So, in this case there will be 2 bytes allocated to variable. Again, if the variable is typecasted into a double variable. So it will be assigned an additional 8 bytes for its representation.
Pertaining to this, my question is that, will the variable, "variable" be assigned 10 bytes of memory, or am I getting something wrong?

Comment: "2 bytes allocated to variable" Maybe. More reading here: [Fundamental Types](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/types). Note that only a minimum size is given for integer types.

Comment: "So it will be assigned an additional 8 bytes for its representation" Very likely this happens in a CPU register and not in RAM, so no additional memory is required..

Comment: You're getting something wrong. `variable` occupies as many bytes as an `int` occupies on your platform via your compiler; `newVariable` occupies whatever a double occupies. Typecasting isn't a memory-consuming operation. It is a conversion.

Comment: @user4581301 I mean the name of the variable is newVariable.

Comment: @EJP you are correct on where you come from, but the double representation of the converted integer will require 8 bytes, won't it?

Comment: @user4581301 actually I changed the variable name altogether. newVariable is now officially, variable2. To answer your question, it was:      
    double sum = (double)variable + newVariable; //newVariable being the variable name

Comment: `(double)variable` doesn't change the storage of `variable`. It makes a value that doesn't occupy storage.   Similar to doing `variable + 1`.

Comment: "Type conversion" is a slightly misleading term – it doesn't convert an object but creates a new object which has the converted value. `(double)variable` has no effect whatsoever on `variable`.

Comment: In fact it's identical to `variable * 1.0`

Comment: got it.. thank you very much.

Answer (score 2):

`(double)variable` is an **rvalue**, so it doesn't formally have any storage.

At a level much lower than C++, the hardware platform's implementation of "addition of two doubles" might mean that it has to put a copy of `variable` in the bit-format of a `double` somewhere in memory so it can be added.

*Probably* the `double` bit-format of `variable` will end up in a the register of an FPU (Floating Point Unit) instead and so will never occupy "memory".

Either way, you can't get at that memory with C++. You would need to tell the compiler to put it somewhere, i.e. make it an **lvalue**, or use it in a way where the C++ standard requires that an an **lvalue** be created, e.g., passing it to a function

That's probably also true of the `int` bit-format of `variable` and of `variable2`, which (even though **lvalue**s) the compiler will hopefully shove them off into (CPU or FPU) registers if you never use the **lvalue**ness, so they won't appear in memory either.

Answer (score 0):

The size of `int` is actually compiler specific, so you can't make any size assumptions about it unless you only work with one compiler. I would strongly recommend #including <[cstdint](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/header/cstdint)> and using the u/intX_t types(i.e. `int16_t`, `int32_t`, `int64_t`) so you know the size of the type you're dealing with. They're aliases that map to whatever built-in types are necessary to achieve a given minimum size.

Cast behavior can vary depending on the type. In general all casts perform a conversion of some kind. It helps to think of casting as "converting", where the conversion rules depend on the type. Unless you're dealing with a custom cast operator, the conversion is going to promote, demote, transform, or reinterpret the bytes of the thing being casted from. Promotions (i.e. `short` => `int`) extend the bits depending on if it's signed or unsigned. Demotions (i.e. `int` => `short`) trim off the higher bits, leaving you with the low part. Transformations (i.e. `int` => `double`) convert from one format to another. Reinterpretations (i.e. `int*` => `double*`) treat the bits as if it were the casted to type.

Your code converts an `int` to a `double` and adds it to another `double`. This has the same effect as if you had left out the cast, because `int` is implicitly casted to `double` when used in an arithmetic expression like that.

Comment: Don't use fixed sizes unless you need fixed sizes. Using the platform types tends to mesh better with the libraries and so on.

Comment: I strongly disagree. It helps with reasoning about the behavior of the types you're dealing with. Suppose you're using int for most of your code and one day you decide to compile it on a different compiler for a different platform. Such compiler, conforming to the standard is allowed to use 16-bits for int, likely breaking your code if you assumed you had 32-bits to work with.